# NSTextField setEnabled

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I have a NSTextField object in my window which has to be disabled when a check box is clicked.

I have written a IBAction to receive the check box click and disabled/enabled the text filed based on the check box state.

```
[mName setEnabled: [mNameCheck state]];
```

This work fine with the basic functionality, but I found some strange behavior.

You update some detail in the text filed and click on check box the text filed get disabled old content.

Example:

- Stage 1: Text filed has the content
  "Name"
- Stage 2: Update the text filed
  content as "Girish"
- Stage 3: Click check box (to disable
  the text filed)
- Stage 4: Text filed disable with the
  content as "Name"

The issue get resolved if I resign the responder and set responder to some other controller before the text field is disabled.

In my case I can not assign the responder to check box(it does not take) or any other controller so I did some thing like bellow which works fine

```
[mName resignFirstResponder];
[mName becomeFirstResponder];
```

resign and assign responder with same controller.

I am just wondering is this solution is correct or any better solution to this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the docs state, **do NOT** call `-resignFirstResponder` or `-becomeFirstResponder` directly. Call `-[NSWindow makeFirstResponder:]` instead. It is acceptable to pass in nil and  status will pass to the window itself.

You could try calling `-[NSWindow selectNextKeyView:]` although I'm not entirely certain what will happen if it doesn't find a valid next key view. Try it and see. If that doesn't work you'll have to fallback to calling `-nextValidKeyView` and `-makeFirstResponder` yourself.

Comment: [NSWindow makeFirstResponder:] - works great.

thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0):

If you set the text field to be **Continuous** in Interface Builder, the value of the field will be set as soon as a change is made in the field rather than when it loses focus. You can programmatically set this value with `[yourTextField setContinuous:YES]`.

Comment: I tried your suggestion of "Continuous" feature usage in Interface builder and even programmatically, it is not solving the issue.

thanks for your suggestion...